# Threads being created and joined over and over in for loops (C)

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, pthreads

I have a written a program that performs Gaussian's elimination in C and returns the L2 norm of a matrix. The program is called like `./exec n k` where n is the size of a nxn matrix and k is the number of threads that will be used to do the program (max 4). I run the program like ./gauss 30 4 and it segfaults.

After using GDB I see there are many more thread exits than anticipated, I think that because my threads are made in the for loop, theyre being joined and created over and over and its causing the seg faults. Can someone please point me in the right direction

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

//globals
double **a, *vect, *bvect, scalar, ratio, sum, delta, *temp;
int i,j,k,ptr, z;
int y,z;
int bvectcount = 0;
int threadcount;
pthread_t workerThreads[4];
typedef struct threader {
    int counter;
    int matrixl;
} threader;
struct timeval start, end;
    void *retval;

int checkargs(int argc, char* argv[]);
// a is matrix, b is vector, x is the solution vector, and n is the size 
double L2(double **a, double *bvect, double *vect, int matrixSize) {
    double sum;
    double res[matrixSize];
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i < matrixSize; i++) {
        sum = (double) 0;
        for (j=0; j < matrixSize; j++) {
            sum += a[i][j] * vect[j];
        }
        res[i] = sum;
    }
    for (i=0; i < matrixSize; i++) {
        res[i] -= vect[i];
    }
    double squaresum = (double) 0;
    for (i=0; i < matrixSize; i++) {
        squaresum += res[i] * res[i];
    }
    return sqrt(squaresum);
}
int checkargs(int argc, char* argv[]){
    if(argc != 3){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Usage is size threadNum\n" );
        exit(1);
    }
}

void *parallelstuff(void *args){
    threader temp = *((threader *)args);
    int i, matrixSize;
    i = temp.counter;
    matrixSize = temp.matrixl;
    double temp2;
    for(j = i + 1; j<matrixSize; j++){
        temp2 = a[j][i]/a[i][i];
        for(z = 0; z<matrixSize + 1; z++){
            a[j][z] = a[j][z] - temp2 * a[i][z];
        }
    }
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    //check for args
    checkargs(argc, argv);
    int matrixSize = atoi(argv[1]);
    int threadNum = atoi(argv[2]);
    //memory allocation
     a = (double**)malloc(matrixSize*sizeof(double*));
    for(i = 0; i < matrixSize ; i++)
        a[i] = (double*)malloc(matrixSize*sizeof(double) * matrixSize);
    vect = (double*)malloc(matrixSize*sizeof(double));
    bvect = (double*)malloc(matrixSize*sizeof(double));
    temp = (double*)malloc(matrixSize*sizeof(double));
    for(i = 0; i < matrixSize; ++i){
        for(j = 0; j < matrixSize + 1; ++j){
            a[i][j] = drand48(); 
        }
    }
    j = 0;
    j += matrixSize;
    for(i = 0; i < matrixSize; ++i){
        bvect[i] = a[i][j];
    }
//generation of scalar matrix (diagonal vector)
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    for(i=0; i<matrixSize; i++){
        scalar = a[i][i];
    //initialization of p to travel throughout matrix
        ptr = i;
    //find largest number in column and row number of it
        for(k = i+1; k < matrixSize; k++){
        if(fabs(scalar) < fabs(a[k][i])){
            //k is row of scalar, while
           scalar = a[k][i];
           ptr = k;
        }
    }
    //swaping the elements of diagonal row and row containing largest no
    for(j = 0; j <= matrixSize; j++)
    {
        temp[0] = a[i][j];
        a[i][j]= a[ptr][j];
        a[ptr][j] = temp[0];
    }
    ratio = a[i][i];
    for(k = 0; k < matrixSize + 1; k++){
        a[i][k] = a[i][k] / ratio;
    }   
    threader stuff;
    stuff.counter = i;
    stuff.matrixl = matrixSize;
    //MAKE EACH THREAD DO SOMETHING DIFF
    //
    // parallelstuff(int i, int matrixSize, double **a){
    for(threadcount = 0; threadcount < threadNum; threadcount++){
        if(pthread_create (&workerThreads[threadcount], NULL, parallelstuff, (void *) &stuff ) != 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: consumer create problem\n");
            exit(1);
            }
        }
    while(threadcount != 0){
        if(pthread_join (workerThreads[threadcount-1], &retval ) != 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: consumer create problem\n");
        exit(1);
        }
        threadcount--;
    }


    //create matrix of n size 
    //backward substitution method
    for(i=matrixSize-1; i >=0; i--){
        for(k = i; k > 0; k--){
            a[k-1][matrixSize] -= a[k-1][i] * a[i][matrixSize];
            a[k-1][i] -= a[k-1][i] * a[i][i];
        }  
    }
    for(i = 0; i < matrixSize; ++i){
        vect[i] = a[i][matrixSize];
        }       
    double l2Norm;
    l2Norm = L2(a, bvect, vect, matrixSize);
    printf("THIS IS L2 NORM: %f\n", l2Norm);
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
    delta = ((end.tv_sec  - start.tv_sec) * 1000000u + 
         end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec) / 1.e6;
    printf("end time: %f\n", delta);
}
        }
```

Terminal returns:

```
(gdb) run 3 4
Starting program: (filepath removed but its there lol)
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7ffff72fe700 (LWP 32612)]
[Thread 0x7ffff72fe700 (LWP 32612) exited]
[New Thread 0x7ffff6afd700 (LWP 32613)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff62fc700 (LWP 32614)]
[Thread 0x7ffff6afd700 (LWP 32613) exited]
[Thread 0x7ffff62fc700 (LWP 32614) exited]
[New Thread 0x7ffff5afb700 (LWP 32615)]
[Thread 0x7ffff5afb700 (LWP 32615) exited]
[New Thread 0x7ffff72fe700 (LWP 32616)]
[Thread 0x7ffff72fe700 (LWP 32616) exited]
[New Thread 0x7ffff6afd700 (LWP 32617)]
[Thread 0x7ffff6afd700 (LWP 32617) exited]
[New Thread 0x7ffff62fc700 (LWP 32618)]
[Thread 0x7ffff62fc700 (LWP 32618) exited]
[New Thread 0x7ffff5afb700 (LWP 32619)]
[Thread 0x7ffff5afb700 (LWP 32619) exited]
[New Thread 0x7ffff72fe700 (LWP 32620)]
[Thread 0x7ffff72fe700 (LWP 32620) exited]
[New Thread 0x7ffff6afd700 (LWP 32621)]
[Thread 0x7ffff6afd700 (LWP 32621) exited]
[New Thread 0x7ffff62fc700 (LWP 32622)]
[Thread 0x7ffff62fc700 (LWP 32622) exited]
[New Thread 0x7ffff5afb700 (LWP 32623)]
[Thread 0x7ffff5afb700 (LWP 32623) exited]
THIS IS L2 NORM: 0.000000
end time: 0.009503
[Inferior 1 (process 32611) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

EDIT: I found something interesting in GDB that tells a lot about the problem. This loops forever and then eventually seg faults. Can someone help me understand what this is?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZMvx.png

Comment: 2 flavors? I have a prototype of checkargs when I used to have main above it, but I moved checkargs above main and just forgot to take the prototype out

Comment: oops, I missed the `;`

Comment: First, get rid of all the casts in your program. They are entirely useless and may just hide bugs. Then don't use arrays of pointers as fake matrices. C has 2D matrices buildin that are much easier to handle. Something like `double (*A)[n] = malloc(sizeof(double[n][n]));` easily does the job. Probability is high that your problem is just your complicated allocation scheme.

Comment: Also, please indent your code properly, this is a pain to read.

Comment: I have indented the out of place lines!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by excessive number of thread exits - it looks to me that there is one thread exit for each thread created.

Comment: the posted code does not compile cleanly. 1)unused parameter bvect  2) unused parameter argv 3) implicit declarion of function: drand48 4) expected declaration or statement at end of input (this is very serious) 5) function checkargs() control reaches end of non-void function 6) function parallesstuff() contgrol reaches end of non-void functions.   Suggest enable all warnings, then re-compile, then fix the warnings, then repost the code.

Comment: Ah, I think that the number of threads is likely ok, but the program runs very erratically.  As you approach a 15x15 matrix, some runs will yield a correct result, while others will segfault.  The probability of it seg faulting increases as the size increases.  For that reason, I believe that the problem is due to something threading related.

Comment: in C, do not cast the returned value from malloc() and family of functions.  Always check (!=NULL) the returned value from malloc to assure the operation was successful

Comment: This might be because my matrix math is quite rusty, but I don't understand what the threads are doing - for each row of the matrix the threads are spun up to do the same work on the same bits of data. So for example, after thread 0 has done some or all of it's work, thread 1 will come along and perform work on the data that has already been transformed.  That doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: the function main() is missing a closing brace "]" somewhere in its' body

Comment: @MichaelBurr - That does sound like a very probable reason for the seg faults.  I'm not exactly sure how to fix it at the moment, but I'll try and think it out.  Also I think I just missed the ending bracket.

Comment: I doubt your problem is caused by using threads. Run your program in gdb and make it segfault. Then use `bt` (in gdb) to print the stack trace. (Make sure your program is compiled with the `-g` flag to include debug information)

Comment: Please don't change your code in the question such that your original problem disappears. This makes things completely useless afterwards.

Comment: Dear Jens Gustedt, I have not. I have changed the code to make it more readable/take your suggestions, but the original problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
for(j = 0; j < matrixSize + 1; ++j){
    a[i][j] = drand48(); 
}
```

is wrong and causes an out of bounds access at the end of each line of the matrix.

You could have a look into `valgrind` or similar tools that help you detect such out-of-bound accesses.

Comment: That actually is an augmented matrix due to Gaussian Elimination, that is intentional, im afraid

Comment: Intentional or not, you don't allocate the space for it.

Comment: I have fixed it.  However, I used an almost identical code for an OpenMP version of this program, and it ran flawlessly.  I understand that my code is wrong, but how did it work beforehand?

Comment: @ericylee314, just bad luck. This depends a lot on the sizes that you allocate, often `malloc` allocates a bit of a "spare" at the end. As I said in another comment, you really should move to use contiguous matrices and regularly use tools like valgrind to check for your memory accesses. Also please think of accepting the answer if it was helpful to you, this puts your question of the radar for others.

Comment: Respectfully, our openmp implementation of the program has worked over 20 times in a row perfectly, I do not think it is a problem with the malloc...however I did give an example where only 4 threads are supposed to be made and 12 were made. For a 3x3 matrix. 4x3=12, it seems like this is the problem and I would like some guidance on that

Comment: Am I missing something?  It looks to me that each line of the matrix is allocated an excessive number of elements: `a[i] = (double*)malloc(matrixSize*sizeof(double) * matrixSize);`

Comment: yes that seemed to be a problem, but we remedied it with  double (*A)[matrixSize] = malloc(sizeof(double[matrixSize][matrixSize +1 ]));
The problem still stands :(

Comment: @ericylee314: I was meaning that the original allocation seemed to allocate not only enough for an access like `a[i][matrixSize]`, but even more (that is not used as far as I can tell).  However, the suggestion to use `valgrind` is a good one; it will likely tell you what's causing the segfault.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, the second `matrixSize` factor was edited in after my answer.

Answer (score -1):

the following code contains comments about the changes.

```
Note: for clarity and maintainability, only one variable per line
Note: for clarity, all braces are included
Note: added brace at end of main() function that should be elsewhere in the function
Note: there are still two compile problems, as noted in the code:
1) function drand48() not defined
2) parameter bvect in function l2 not used.

Please fix all the remaining problems in the code and re-post

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h> // sqrt()
#include <omp.h>
#include <time.h> // time() gettimeofday()
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h> // memcpy()

struct threader
{
    int counter;
    int matrixl;
};

//globals
double **a;
double *vect;
double *bvect;
double scalar;
double ratio;
double sum;
double delta;
double *temp;

int i;
int j;
int k;
int ptr;
int z;
int y;
//int z; <-- second declaration of same variable

int bvectcount = 0; // unused variable

int threadcount;
pthread_t workerThreads[4];

struct timeval start; // beginn execution time
struct timeval end;   // end    execution time

void *retval;

// prototypes
// a is matrix, b is vector, x is the solution vector, and n is the size
double L2(double **a, double *bvect, double *vect, int matrixSize);

// thread function
void *parallelstuff(void *args);

// check command line argumen counts
int checkargs(int argc, char* argv[]);







int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //check for args
    checkargs(argc, argv);

    int matrixSize = atoi(argv[1]);
    if( 0 >= matrixSize )
    {
        // handle error; exit(1);
    }

    int threadNum = atoi(argv[2]);
    if( (0 >= threadNum) || (4 < threadNum) )
    {
        // handle error; exit(1);
    }

    //memory allocation
    if( NULL == (a = malloc(matrixSize*sizeof(double*)) ) )
    {
        // perror(); call cleanup; exit(1);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < matrixSize ; i++)
    {
        if( NULL == (a[i] = malloc(matrixSize*sizeof(double) * matrixSize) ) )
        {
            //perror(); call cleanup; exit(1);
        }
    }


    if( NULL == (vect  = malloc(matrixSize*sizeof(double)) ) )
    {
        // perror(); call cleanup; exit(1);
    }

    if( NULL == (bvect = malloc(matrixSize*sizeof(double)) ) )
    {
        // perror(); call cleanup; exit(1);
    }

    if( NULL == (temp  = malloc(matrixSize*sizeof(double)) ) )
    {
        // perror(); call cleanup; exit(1);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < matrixSize; ++i)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < matrixSize + 1; ++j)
        {
            a[i][j] = drand48(); // where is this function defined?
        }
    }


    j = matrixSize;

    for(i = 0; i < matrixSize; ++i)
    {
        bvect[i] = a[i][j];
    }

    //generation of scalar matrix (diagonal vector)
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL); // time how long this takes to execute

    for(i=0; i<matrixSize; i++)
    {
        scalar = a[i][i];

        //initialization of p to travel throughout matrix
        ptr = i;

        //find largest number in column and row number of it
        for(k = i+1; k < matrixSize; k++)
        {
            if(fabs(scalar) < fabs(a[k][i]))
            {
                //k is row of scalar, while
                scalar = a[k][i];
                ptr = k;
            }
        }

        //swaping the elements of diagonal row and row containing largest no
        for(j = 0; j <= matrixSize; j++)
        {
            temp[0] = a[i][j];
            a[i][j]= a[ptr][j];
            a[ptr][j] = temp[0];
        }

        ratio = a[i][i];

        for(k = 0; k < matrixSize + 1; k++)
        {
            a[i][k] = a[i][k] / ratio;
        }

        struct threader stuff;
        stuff.counter = i;
        stuff.matrixl = matrixSize;

        // parallelstuff(int i, int matrixSize, double **a){

        for(threadcount = 0; threadcount < threadNum; threadcount++)
        {
            if( pthread_create( &workerThreads[threadcount], NULL, parallelstuff, (void *) &stuff ) )
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: consumer create problem\n");
                exit(1);
            }
        }


        while(threadcount != 0)
        {
            if(pthread_join (workerThreads[threadcount-1], &retval ) != 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: consumer create problem\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            threadcount--;
        }

        //create matrix of n size
        //backward substitution method
        for(i=matrixSize-1; i >=0; i--)
        {
            for(k = i; k > 0; k--)
            {
                a[k-1][matrixSize] -= a[k-1][i] * a[i][matrixSize];
                a[k-1][i] -= a[k-1][i] * a[i][i];
            }
        }

        for(i = 0; i < matrixSize; ++i)
        {
            vect[i] = a[i][matrixSize];
        }

        double l2Norm;
        l2Norm = L2(a, bvect, vect, matrixSize);
        printf("THIS IS L2 NORM: %f\n", l2Norm);
        gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
        delta =
            ((end.tv_sec  - start.tv_sec) * 1000000u + end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec) / 1.e6;
        printf("end time: %f\n", delta);

        return(0);
    } // supply missing closing brace, just for testing, where should this actually be placed?
    } // end function: main


double L2(double **a, double *bvect, double *vect, int matrixSize) // unused param: bvect
{
    double sum;
    double res[matrixSize];
    int i;
    int j;

    for (i=0; i < matrixSize; i++)
    {
        sum = 0.0;

        for (j=0; j < matrixSize; j++)
        {
            sum += a[i][j] * vect[j];
        }
        res[i] = sum;
    }

    for (i=0; i < matrixSize; i++)
    {
        res[i] -= vect[i];
    }

    double squaresum = 0.0;

    for (i=0; i < matrixSize; i++)
    {
        squaresum += res[i] * res[i];
    }

    return sqrt(squaresum);
} // end function: L2


// this function changes global array 'a[]'
// to avoid race conditions, a mutex should be used to lock the resource (a[])
//  while it is being modified
void *parallelstuff(void *args)
{
    struct threader temp;    // this shadows global 'temp' variable
    memcpy ( &temp, (struct threader *)args, sizeof(struct threader) );

    int j;
    int z;

    int i = temp.counter;
    int matrixSize = temp.matrixl;

    double temp2 = 0.0;

    for(j = i + 1; j<matrixSize; j++)
    {
        temp2 = a[j][i] / a[i][i];
        for(z = 0; z<matrixSize + 1; z++) // this will access memory beyond the bounds of 2d matrix a[]
        {
            a[j][z] = a[j][z] - temp2 * a[i][z];
        }
    }

    pthread_exit( NULL );
} // end function: parallelstuff


int checkargs(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Usage: %s size threadNum\n", argv[0] );
        exit(1);
    }

    return( 0 );
} // end function: checkargs
```